# What machine learning approach should I use for a recommandation system based on attributes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am trying to predict what would be the best movie I can recommend for a person based on criteria like gender, age and mood. I have a vector like this (1,0,0...1).

My first approach was trying to predict what grade a person would give to a movie based on this vector then make a ranking based on these grades.

So a in the dataset a person is defined by a vector (1,0,...1)
                      movie is defined by a vector  (1,0,...1)
                      and the grade that a person gave to a movie.

What would you recommend ?

Thanks !

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is opinion based. But I also urge other people who look at this comment to answer where exactly questions of this nature be asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I think you can use an Association Pattern Mining algorithm. The best known of the Frequent Itemset Mining Algorithms for mining association rules is the Apriori algorithm.
In your case the attributes of a person, such as : gender, age and mood would be the items, and the recommended movie would be the client. 
Each tuple: [person attributes - recommended movie], represents an itemset. 
You can check chapter 4 of the book Data Mining The Textbook by Charu C. Aggarwal
https://doc.lagout.org/Others/Data%20Mining/Data%20Mining_%20The%20Textbook%20%5BAggarwal%202015-04-14%5D.pdf